# java generics classcastexception

Tags: java, generics

Exceptions are thrown because the type "E" is read as the class Object and not the parameter that was specified. Is that how it should be?

```
@Override
public E[] getAllEntities() {
    String jpdlQuery = String.format("select e from %s e", entityShortName);
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpdlQuery, entityClass);
    return (E[]) query.getResultList().toArray();
}
```

Comment: From [`Collection#toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()): "_The returned array's runtime component type is `Object`_". Besides that, arrays and generics don't mix well; generics are subject to type-erasure yet arrays know their component type at run time. You should change the return type to `List<E>`, declare the type of `query` as `TypedQuery<E>` instead of `Query`, and then simply return the result of `getResultList()` directly rather than convert it into an array.

Comment: And you should probably just use Spring Data JPA to autogenerate this code for you in a type-safe and testable manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "genericize" the method,
`public <E> E[] getAllEntities()` or else in the class definition somewhere.

HOWEVER, mixing generics and arrays is a Really Bad Idea, since arrays have their base type at runtime and generics do not. You will get a compile warning from the cast `(E[])`.

Also, you left out the generic result on `createQuery()`, which in the form you used returns a `TypedQuery<E>`. If you used the more specific return value you wouldn't need the cast. Furthermore, you wouldn't be returning a raw `List`. Don't use raw types.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery-
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html

Comment: The `E` in the OP's code is likely from the class declaration and adding `<E>` to the method would just hide the class' type parameter (likely breaking things). Also, the OP calls `getResultList().toArray()` so they aren't trying to case `List` to `E[]` but are rather trying to cast `Object[]` to `E[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays know their component type at runtime, so when you create an array, you must provide the component type at runtime, and arrays created with different component types are instances of different runtime classes. On the other hand, instances of generic classes don't know their generic type arguments at runtime.

`Collection` has two `.toArray()` methods:

1. `Object[] toArray()`: this method takes no parameters, and it returns an array whose runtime class is always `Object[]`. This is because the collection doesn't have any idea what its component type is at runtime, and without any arguments, it has no information about what component type of array to create at runtime.
2. `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`: this method takes in an array parameter, and it returns an array with the same runtime class as the one passed in. It does this by either returning the same array object, or (if the array passed in is not big enough) extracting the component type of the runtime class of the array passed in, and using that to create a new array object of the same runtime class.

You have used the `.toArray()` method without arguments; thus it will always return an array object whose runtime class is `Object[]`, as if created by `new Object[...]`. If you want your `getAllEntities()` method to return an array of the right runtime type `E[]`, it would need to somehow know at runtime what `E` is; to do that, you would need to make the caller pass in an argument of type `E[]` or `Class<E>`. For example,

```
public E[] getAllEntities(E[] array) {
    //...
    return query.getResultList().toArray(array);
}
```

The alternative would be to return a `List`, which does not need to know it component type at runtime, so you can create a `List<E>` without knowing what `E` is at runtime:

```
public List<E> getAllEntities() {
    //...
    return query.getResultList();
}
```